# Amazon EC2: How to make SSH remember the server's key

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I connect to my `amazon EC2 Ubuntu 18.04` instant using `SSH`. Each time I input the SSH command, it asks me about trusting the key. And I answer `yes`. Next time it asks me again.

> ssh -i "my_key.pem" ubuntu@mydomain.myregion.amazonaws.com The
>   authenticity of host 'mydomain.myregion.amazonaws.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)'
>   can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:[some string].
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

I checked the `/home/.ssh/known_hosts.txt` file. It repeatedly saves the file each time. Please note that I have previously missed up with this file. Then I uninstalled then reinstalled the SSH using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server.
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

How can I make `SSH` remember my server's key and stop repeatedly writing the key in the `known_hosts.txt` as this is going to make the file extremely huge.